# Running query on wordpress db and return values based on custom meta from logged in user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

In wordpress I'm trying to build a query that returns a list of data from a table where there is a match on a custom field I created for users that contains a reference number.

The query I have currently returns all the information from the test table, what I'd LIKE to do is return the information where the search term is the value in the custom field of the currently logged in user.

This is my current code:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM test_table" );
foreach ( $result as $print )   {

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $print->customernumber.'</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $print->field2.'</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $print->field3.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

How do I go about modifying it? What I want to do is say something along the lines of SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE customernumber = (the value of the customernumber field for the current logged in user)

Do I need to use something like get_user_meta ? I'm still kinda new to wordpress queries...

I'm not sure if I've explained this as clearly as I could, but I'm grateful for any help / advice... thanks :)

Comment: Did you have that value stored in a session or something?

Comment: if you mean the customernumber I believe it's stored as part of the meta for the current logged in user - I'm fairly sure it can be called using the get_user_meta command, I'm just not sure of the right syntax really

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using SQL queries directly (believe me, you'll regret it in the end) use wordpress' own methods. Try something like this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$customer_number = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, "customernumber")
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $customer_number . "</td>
<td>" . $current_user->user_login . "</td>
<td>" . $current_user->ID . "</td>
</tr>";
```

The last two have been added in for an example purpose but you can modify that to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for replying - I don't actually want to return the customernumber - I want to use it to search and return all records in a separate table (populated by incoming xml files) that match the same value in the customernumber field for the current logged in user, if that makes sense?

Comment: Sure, but you could use the code above to achieve that too. Use the `$customer_number = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, "customernumber");` variable to get the current customer number and search your XML files using a custom method with that parameter.

Comment: I got as far as:

`code  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_number = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, "customernumber");
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE            customernumber = ".$customer_number."" );
    foreach ( $result as $print ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $print->customernumber.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $print->field2.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $print->field3.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }`

and it seems no joy. Perhaps I need another solution

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in as a user that has a user meta key/value of customernumber? That one's caught me out a few times. Again, what's with the custom table? It'd be much more preferential to create a custom post type for your data and let wordpress handle it all

Comment: haha yeah that's the first thing I checked - there's only an admin user at the moment, with a value in the customernumber field that matches the one in the db.

Essentially it's because the data is a dump from a sales entry system that's imported via CRON every night from xml files... just the way they want it, me personally I'd rather do it all in woocommerce... but what do I know